# How to insert PAGE_NUMBER and PAGE_COUNT in footer

Tags: php, google-docs-api

I'm looking for exemple of paragraph and element paragraph in footer.
I'd tried but i only can insert text in footer:

```
$requests = array (new \Google_Service_Docs_Request(array(
    'insertText' => array(
        'location' => array(
            'segmentId' => $segmentId,
                'index' => 0
            ),
            "text" => 'My Text'
        )
)),
```

I tried to implement new footers like this :

```
$footers = array(
        new \Google_Service_Docs_Footer(array(
            'footerId' => $segmentId,
            'content' => [
                'paragraph' => [
                    'element' => [
                        'textRun' => [
                            'content' => 'My Text - '
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        )),
        new \Google_Service_Docs_Footer(array(
            'footerId' => $segmentId,
            'content' => [
                  'paragraph' => [
                      'element' => [
                          'AutoText' => [
                              'type' => 'PAGE_NUMBER'
                          ]
                      ]
                  ]
            ]
        )),
        new \Google_Service_Docs_Footer(array(
            'footerId' => $segmentId,
            'content' => [
                'paragraph' => [
                    'element' => [
                        'AutoText' => [
                            'type' => 'PAGE_COUNT'
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ))
    );
    $document->setFooters($footers);
```

Can we manage paragraph of Footer ?

Comment: can you please tell me , how you got footer id? In your case , i can see you have passed one variable $segmentId. Can you tell me what values you have assigned in $segmentId. I am stuck in this point to get footer id. It would be a great help if you can answer me this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can insert [AutoText](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents#autotext) through the API. There is no valid [request from batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request) that can be used for that (text inserted via [InsertTextRequest](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request#InsertTextRequest) has to be a string). As a result of this, `PAGE_NUMBER` and `PAGE_COUNT` can only be set through the UI: if you're using the API, you can only retrieve them.

I'd suggest you to file a Feature Request in [this Issue Tracker component](https://issuetracker.google.com/components/555502) regarding this issue.

#### Reference:

- [AutoText](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents#autotext)
- [documents.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request)
- [InsertTextRequest](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request#InsertTextRequest)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, indeed after a day searching solutions, 
it seems there is no solution. I'll file a feature request like you suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Issue in progress https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/149275293
i keep you in touch when i have a feedback