# Can we insert page numbers in footer in google docs using google docs api with PHP?

Tags: php, google-api, google-docs, google-docs-api

I want to insert page numbers in google docs using google docs api with PHP. It is possible to insert page numbers in google docs using the api? [image]

Can we insert page numbers like this as shown in above picture? If yes, then how I can achieve that? I also went through this link https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents#DocumentStyle.FIELDS.page_number_start for pageNumberStart but didn't know is this the same thing or whether this is something else, because when I used it like this-

```
new Google_Service_Docs_Request(array(
    'updateDocumentStyle' => [
        'documentStyle' => [
            'pageNumberStart' => 1,
        ],
        'fields' => 'pageNumberStart',
    ],
)),
```

then it shows me nothing.

Is there any way to insert page numbers in google docs using google docs api with PHP.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to insert PAGE\_NUMBER and PAGE\_COUNT in footer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60186643/how-to-insert-page-number-and-page-count-in-footer)

Comment: @lamblichus, I already visited the link you have mentioned but unfortunately i don't understand that part of answer given .As my simple question is , Is there a way to insert page numbers or not and if yes then how. And the link you have mentioned doesn't give me a clear answer to my question,

Comment: The answer is no, you can't. Also mentioned in that answer: `As a result of this, PAGE_NUMBER and PAGE_COUNT can only be set through the UI: if you're using the API, you can only retrieve them.`